# Dynamic Attributes (nested) used as Grid Columns in ExtJS

Tags: c#, json, extjs

I tried to use the dynamic attributes approach within my prototype mongoDB application.

Basically the approach just gives you something like this:

```
{
  SKU: "Y32944EW",
  type: "shoes",
  attr: [
      { "k": "manufacturer", 
        "v": "ShoesForAll",
      },
      { "k": "color", 
        "v": "blue",
      },
      { "k": "style", 
        "v": "comfort",
      },
      { "k": "size", 
        "v": "7B"
      }
  ]
}
```

(Source: http://askasya.com/post/dynamicattributes).

The problem is that for example Kendo Grid does not support such nested structures in their data source.

Does anyone know if Sencha ExtJS Grid Component can do this?

---

**Update:** SKU should be a column and each v of the attr array should be a column.

---

**Update:** I am trying to setup a sencha fiddle with the help of your answer.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/evc

app.js (rev2)

```
// create the new type
Ext.data.Types.DYNAMIC = {
    convert: function(value, record) {
       for (var i = 0, ln = value.length; i < ln; i++) {
                var item = value[i];
                record.set(item.k, item.v);
            }
            return '';
    },
    type: 'dynamic',
    sortType: Ext.data.SortTypes.none
};

// define a model
Ext.define('TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: "_id",type: "string"},
    {name: "attr",type:  Ext.data.Types.DYNAMIC}],
    idProperty: '_id'
});
// create a store with the model assigned
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'MyStore',
    model: 'TestModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/data.json',
        reader: {
            idProperty: '_id',
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Grid',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyStore'),
    columns: []

}); 

Ext.widget('window',{height: 200,width: 400, items: [grid ] }).show();

store.on('metachange', function(store, meta) {
    grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
});
```

data.json (rev2)

```
   {
    "metaData": {
        "idProperty": "_id",
        "rootProperty": "data",
        "fields": [
            { "name": "_id","type": "string" },
            { "name": "de", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "en", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "fr", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "attr", "type":  "dynamic"}
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "header": "de",
                "dataIndex": "de"
            },
            {
                "header": "en",
                "dataIndex": "en"
            }
            ,
            {
                "header": "fr",
                "dataIndex": "fr"
            }
        ]
    },
 "data":     
        [
            {"_id": "MyTextId1",
                "attr":[
                    {
                        "k": "de",
                        "v": "GermanText Sample"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k": "en",
                        "v": "English Text Sample"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k": "fr",
                        "v": "French Text Sample"
                    },
                ]
            },
           {"_id": "MyTextId2",
               "attr":[
                   {
                       "k": "de",
                       "v": "GermanText Sample 1"
                   }, 
                   {
                       "k": "en",
                       "v": "English Text Sample 1"
                   }, 
                   {
                       "k": "fr",
                       "v": "French Text Sample1 1"
                   },
               ]
           }
        ]
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
 Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.[object Object]
```

---

**Update:**
Works with the snippet posted in the last edit of sra. Thank you!

[image: Ext JS 5]

Comment: What structure is good for kendo-grid based on your sample document?

Comment: I have an idea how to do this in ExtJS 5 but I need to know how do you want visualize your data structure? For example if it has to be flat? (i.e. attr merged to the same level as type and SKU) or maybe like here (expand row): http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#customer-grid

Comment: The example looks interesting. For this specific use case it can all be on the same level. SKU should be a column and each v of the attr array should be a column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes you can. And most of it is already Build in. Lets's start with the basics**

[Response MetaData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json)

The server can return metadata in its response, in addition to the record data, that describe attributes of the data set itself or are used to reconfigure the Reader. To pass metadata in the response you simply add a metaData attribute to the root of the response data. The metaData attribute can contain anything, but supports a specific set of properties that are handled by the Reader if they are present:

```
root: the property name of the root response node containing the record data
totalProperty: property name for the total number of records in the data
successProperty: property name for the success status of the response
messageProperty: property name for an optional response message
fields: Config used to reconfigure the Model's fields before converting the response data into records
```

An initial Reader configuration containing all of these properties might look like this ("fields" would be included in the Model definition, not shown):

```
reader: {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'root',
    totalProperty  : 'total',
    successProperty: 'success',
    messageProperty: 'message'
}
```

If you were to pass a response object containing attributes different from those initially defined above, you could use the metaData attribute to reconifgure the Reader on the fly. For example:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "ok": true,
    "msg": "Users found",
    "users": [{
        "userId": 123,
        "name": "Ed Spencer",
        "email": "ed@sencha.com"
    }],
    "metaData": {
        "root": "users",
        "totalProperty": 'count',
        "successProperty": 'ok',
        "messageProperty": 'msg'
    }
}
```

You can also place any other arbitrary data you need into the metaData attribute which will be ignored by the Reader, but will be accessible via the Reader's metaData property (which is also passed to listeners via the Proxy's metachange event (also relayed by the store). Application code can then process the passed metadata in any way it chooses.

A simple example for how this can be used would be customizing the fields for a Model that is bound to a grid. By passing the fields property the Model will be automatically updated by the Reader internally, but that change will not be reflected automatically in the grid unless you also update the column configuration. You could do this manually, or you could simply pass a standard grid column config object as part of the metaData attribute and then pass that along to the grid. Here's a very simple example for how that could be accomplished:

```
// response format:
{
    ...
    "metaData": {
        "fields": [
            { "name": "userId", "type": "int" },
            { "name": "name", "type": "string" },
            { "name": "birthday", "type": "date", "dateFormat": "Y-j-m" }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "text": "User ID", "dataIndex": "userId", "width": 40 },
            { "text": "User Name", "dataIndex": "name", "flex": 1 },
            { "text": "Birthday", "dataIndex": "birthday", "flex": 1, "format": 'Y-j-m', "xtype": "datecolumn" }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Reader will automatically read the meta fields config and rebuild the Model based on the new fields, but to handle the new column configuration you would need to handle the metadata within the application code. This is done simply enough by handling the metachange event on either the store or the proxy, e.g.:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    listeners: {
        'metachange': function(store, meta) {
            myGrid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**That for the basics. Now the details for your data-structure:**

first we need a converter function to read the custom data

```
convert: function(value,record) {
    for(var i=0,ln=value.length;i<ln;i++) {
        var item = value[i];
        record.set(item.k,item.v);
    }
    return ''; let's save memory an drop it
}
```

and we can publish the basic fields (and columns (not displayed)) - but we don't need becaouse the metachange can handle it all

```
{ name: "SKU", type:"string") }, // don't forget to mark this as the idProperty in the reader and in the model
{ name: "type", type:"string") },
{ name: "attr", type:"auto", convert: convert() }
```

all fields & columns below are published by the server with metachange

```
"metaData": {
    "fields": [
        { name: "SKU", type:"string") }, 
        { name: "type", type:"string") },
        { name: "attr", type:"auto", convert: convert() },
        // and the dynamic datafields
        { name: "manufacturer", type:"string" },
        { name: "style", type:"string" },
        // ... and so on
    ],
    "columns": [
        { "text": "ID", "dataIndex": "SKU", "width": 40 },
        { "text": "ID", "dataIndex": "SKU", "width": 40 },
        // and the dynamic datacolumns
        { "text": "Manufacturer", "dataIndex": "manufacturer" },
        { "text": "Style", "dataIndex": "stlye" },
        // ... and so on
    ]
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I recommend to either create your own reader which transform the data to a normalized JSON before processing it further or your own [Ext.data.Types](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Types) type. Because I think it is a bit faster I recommend to create your own data-type. The downside in your case is, that the field with this property need to be always AFTER the dynamic field, otherwise the reader will override the dynamic fields.

Here is a snipped that I tested with 4.2.3

```
// create the new type
Ext.data.Types.DYNAMIC = {
    convert: function(value, record) {
        for (var i = 0, ln = value.length; i < ln; i++) {
            var item = value[i];
            record.data[item.k] = item.v;
        }
        return '';
    },
    type: 'dynamic',
    sortType: Ext.data.SortTypes.none
};

// define a model
Ext.define('TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: "_id",type: "string"},
    {name: "attr",type: "dynamic"}],
    idProperty: '_id'
});
// create a store with the model assigned
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'MyStore',
    model: 'TestModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/data.json',
        reader: {
            idProperty: '_id',
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Grid',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyStore'),
    columns: []

}); 

Ext.widget('window',{height: 200,width: 400, items: [grid ] }).show();

store.on('metachange', function(store, meta) {
    grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
});
```

And the data

```
{
    "metaData": {
        "idProperty": "_id",
        "rootProperty": "data",
        "fields": [
            { "name": "_id","type": "string" },
            { "name": "de", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "en", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "fr", "type":"string" },
            { "name": "attr", "type": "dynamic" }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "header": "de",
                "dataIndex": "de"
            },
            {
                "header": "en",
                "dataIndex": "en"
            }
            ,
            {
                "header": "fr",
                "dataIndex": "fr"
            }
        ]
    },
 "data":     
        [
            {"_id": "MyTextId1",
                "attr":[
                    {
                        "k": "de",
                        "v": "GermanText Sample"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k": "en",
                        "v": "English Text Sample"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "k": "fr",
                        "v": "French Text Sample"
                    },
                ]
            },
           {"_id": "MyTextId2",
               "attr":[
                   {
                       "k": "de",
                       "v": "GermanText Sample 1"
                   }, 
                   {
                       "k": "en",
                       "v": "English Text Sample 1"
                   }, 
                   {
                       "k": "fr",
                       "v": "French Text Sample1 1"
                   },
               ]
           }
        ]
}
```

---

Edit:

This snipped is tested in 5.1 and it worked

```
Ext.data.Types.DYNAMIC = {
    convert: function(value, record) {
        for (var i = 0, ln = value.length; i < ln; i++) {
            var item = value[i];
            record.data[item.k] = item.v;
        }
        return '';
    },
    type: 'dynamic',
    sortType: Ext.data.SortTypes.none
};


Ext.define('Ext.data.field.Dynamic', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.field.Field',

    alias: 'data.field.dynamic',

    sortType: 'none',

    isDynamicField: true,

    convert: function(value, record) {
        for (var i = 0, ln = value.length; i < ln; i++) {
            var item = value[i];
            record.data[item.k] = item.v;
        }
        return '';
    },

    getType: function() {
        return 'dynamic';
    }
});


Ext.define('TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: "_id",type: "string"},{name: "attr",type: "dynamic"}],
    idProperty: '_id'
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'MyStore',
    model: 'TestModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/qat/Content/TST/data.js',
        reader: {
            idProperty: '_id',
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Grid',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyStore'),
    dockedItems: [{xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('MyStore'), dock: 'bottom',displayInfo: false}],
    columns: []

}); 
Ext.widget('window',{height: 200,width: 400, items: [grid ] }).show();

store.on('metachange', function(store, meta) {
    // Apply the column definitions to the Grid
    grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it looks very comprehensive. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is very similar to what I wanted to show. Just for the record, you can create Ext.data.Model and specify it in store definition by property `model` instead of `metaData`. +1

Comment: @rzymek Well, that is not really option, it is  a must (I leave the auto-model asside). Otherwise there are no model fields that we can update with our metadata-fields ;) You can just spare the fields when defining the model, because theoretically you can set them all with metadata.

Comment: If we assume that some configurations of "dynamic datafields" are known then we could create appropriate models and spare response size. However if we have many configurations then you're right, the only option is `metaData`.

Comment: In addition, if we want to manage records using Data Session then I'm afraid that Ext requires defined models in order to properly associate records, track changes and send changes to the server. (however I haven't tested Data Session with metadata, maybe it can be done)

Comment: @rzymek It will work, as long as you do it the right way. And no, you cannot spare `response size`, because if you change the fields or columns you have to supply the whole set and not just the `new part`. Anyway, a metadata change is normally done once at the start with the loading request, so it will not affect any record. As a side note: I prevent using model associations if I can (which is in 99% of all cases)

Comment: @sra, OK I see. Could you explain why don't you use model associations?

Comment: I updated my answer. I am trying to setup a sencha fiddle. It does not work yet as expected. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/evc (Please note: I just started with Ext JS development)

Comment: @sra: thank you I modified my question and updated my fiddle. I have got a "Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.[object Object]" error (the fiddle uses another framework version)

Comment: @Matthias Don't try this with the sencha Fiddle because it will override your custom data type. Try it in your own environment. The difference between 4.x and 5.x is only by the definition of the reader root property, wich is `root` in 4.x and `rootProperty` in 5.x

Comment: { name: "attr", type: "dynamic" } in the model breaks the example. It then only asks for /.js&dc=bla instead of /data.json

Comment: @sra: do you know the cause of this behaviour? Should I open a new question?

Comment: @Matthias OK, again a edit with a working snipped. Now for ExtJS 5.1

Comment: @sra: Thank you it works perfect! (In your latest snippet you may remove the first dynamic definition)